# How to use multi-threading correctly in python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-multithreading

Recently, I started learning about threading and i wanted to implement it in the following code.

```
import timeit
start = timeit.default_timer()
def func(num):
    s = [(i, j, k) for i in range(num) for j in range(num) for k in range(num)]
    return s
z = 150
a,b = func(z),func(z)
print(a[:5], b[:5])
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print("time: ", stop - start)
```

the time it took was:

```
time:  3.7628489000000003
```

So I tried to use the Threading module and modified the code as:

```
import timeit
from threading import Thread
start = timeit.default_timer()


def func(num):
    s = [(i, j, k) for i in range(num) for j in range(num) for k in range(num)]
    print(s[:5])

a = Thread(target=func, args=(150,))
b = Thread(target=func, args=(150,))
a.start()
b.start()
a.join()
b.join()
stop = timeit.default_timer()
print("time: ", stop - start)
```

the time it took was:

```
time:  4.2522736
```

But, its supposed to get halved instead it increases. Is there anything wrong in my implementation?
Please explain what went wrong or is there a better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have encountered what is known as Global Interpreter Lock, GIL for short.

Threads in python are not "real" threads, that is to say that they do not execute simultaneously, but atomic operations in them are computed in sequence in some order (that order is often hard to predetermine)

This means that threads of `threading` library are useful when you need to wait for many blocking things simultaneously. This is usually listening to a network connection when one thread sits at `receive()` -method until something is received. 
Other threads can keep doing other things and don't have to keep constantly checking the connection.
Real performance gains however cannot be achieved with `threading`

There is another library, called `multiprocessing` which does implement real threads that actually execute simultaneously. Using `multiprocessing` is in many ways similar to `threading` library but requires a little bit more work and care. I've come to realise that this divide between `threading` and `multiprocessing` is a good and useful thing. Threads in `threading` all have access to the same complete namespace, and as long as race conditions are taken care of, they operate in the same universe.

Threads in `multiprocessing` (I should use term process here) on the other hand are separated by the chasm of different namespaces after the child process is started. One has to use specialized communication queues and shared namespace objects when transmitting information between them. This will quickly require hundreds of lines of boilerplate code.